# Why is PropertyInfo[] not populating?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms, dataset, typeof

I am currently working on rebuilding a WebForms application to MVC. Part of this conversion requires mapping DataSets and DataTables into objects. The method I am using to accomplish this is:

```
    public static List<T> DataTableToEntityList<T>(DataTable sourceDataTable, params PropertyMapper[] propertyMappings) where T : class, new()
    {
        List<T> entityList = new List<T>();

        if (sourceDataTable != null)
        {
            // Get all properties of the Type T
            PropertyInfo[] entityProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

            foreach (DataRow dr in sourceDataTable.Rows)
            {
                // Create Instance of the Type T
                T entity = new T();
                PopulateEntityClass<T>(entity, dr, entityProperties, propertyMappings);
                entityList.Add(entity);
            }
        }

        return entityList;
    }
```

The main program is:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        DataTable dt = program.createData();

        List<superadminAction> list = Helper.DataMappingHelper.DataTableToEntityList<superadminAction>(dt, null);


        foreach(superadminAction action in list)
        {
            if (action.Title != null)
                Console.WriteLine(action.Title);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("null values");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

The object I am converting to is:

```
public class superadminAction
{
    public int SuperAdminActionCounter;
    public string Procedure, Title, Description, TemplateDescription; 
}
```

}

I can't figure out why I am unable to access the properties in the *Main(...)* function.

Any ideas would be much much appreciated.

Comment: Probably, because you don't have a properties in `superadminAction` class

Comment: Not having properties wouldn't throw an exception; it would return an empty array.

Comment: @madreflection I guess, that exception happens somewhere inside `PopulateEntityClass<T>(entity, dr, entityProperties, propertyMappings);` call. @urizark You've also passed a `null` value for `propertyMappings`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski thank you; adding properties fixed the problem!

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: Maybe, but that's not what the question states. It states that `typeof(T)` throws the exception and we see that before `PopulateEntityClass<T>` is called.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski yes I purposely did that only because in the *PopulateEntityClass<T>(...)* if the propertyMappings == null the mapping will be done on the columnNames of the DataTable

Comment: @madreflection sorry if my question wasn't very clear; I am only beginning to work with this code and I am not entirely familiar with everything

Comment: @urizark: It'll be a good learning experience for you, then. Fortunately, Pavel was able to divine the nature of the problem in spite of the misleading description. Speaking of which, you should edit the title and the question to be more accurate so that it'll be useful to future readers.

Comment: @madreflection absolutely, I'll do that now. Thank you for your help

Comment: @urizark: That's a much better title for this problem. Well done.

Comment: @urizark System.Reflection for mapping property values, especially within a loop, is a recipe for disaster. Reflection can add huge value to your app, but not like this. It may save you some coding time, but the performance hit in your use case can almost never be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Procedure, Title, Description etc are fields not properties. To get them, use typeof(T).GetFields().